# Chained Lookups in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a very large pandas dataframe with two columns that I'd like to recursively lookup.

Given input of the following dataframe:

```
NewID, OldID
1, 0
2, 1
3, 2
5, 4
7, 6
8, 7
9, 5
```

I'd like to generate the series OriginalId:

```
NewID, OldId, OriginalId
1, 0, 0
2, 1, 0
3, 2, 0
5, 4, 4
7, 6, 6
8, 7, 6
9, 5, 4
```

This can be trivially solved by iterating over the sorted data and for each row, checking if OldId points to an existing NewId and if so, setting OriginalId to OriginalId for that row.

This can be solved by iteratively merging and updating columns, by the following algorithm:

```
Merge OldId to NewId. 
For any one that did not match, set OriginalId to OldId. 
If they did match, set OldId to OldId for the matched column. 
Repeat until OriginalIds are all filled in.
```

Feels like there should be a pandas friendly way to do this via cumulative sums or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
df.set_index('NewID', inplace=True)
df.loc[:, 'OriginalId'] = df.loc[df['OldId'], 'OldID'].fillna(df['OldId'])
```

Comment: I don't think this works, unless run repeatedly until no NaN are present to fill. Consider the 3, 2 row. It will lookup where NewId == OldID and get an OldID of 1. But we require repeating the operation and calculating 0 as the original ID. This looks like a panda efficient implementation of the algorithm described above. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You mean you need to keep finding `'OldID'` till you run out of them?

Comment: Yes, need to keep chaining OldId until you find an entry such that OldId is not in the set of all NewId.

Comment: Also, one loop of this implementation is fairly slow on even a 100K row dataframe. And I'd like to do this over millions of rows. At the moment, old school python iteration or an apply function is the fastest answer I've got.